# SurfaceView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to implement a custom SurfaceView in my activity's XML file, and then reference it within the activity's code for drawing etc. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.animateddrawable.MainActivity.DrawingPanel
```

MainActivity Code:

```
package com.example.animateddrawable;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
...


com.example.animateddrawable.MainActivity.DrawingPanel.PanelThread;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dp = new DrawingPanel(this, null);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        public DrawingPanel( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    }
}
```

XML Code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.example.animateddrawable.MainActivity.DrawingPanel
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "fill_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add a  constructor like this:

```
public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
public DrawingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
```

add this to your other constructer as well:

```
 getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Comment: Done, now I have a new error - yaaaaay!

    attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/example/animateddrawable/MainActivity$DrawingPanel"

Comment: It is good practice to separate your custom View to another class, can you try this? and  why are you using this: `dp = new DrawingPanel(this, null);` ?

Comment: I tried separating it into another Java file, but does that not make it more complex in terms of manipulating the onDraw method? I'm relatively new to OOP, so this is all a bit of a learning curve for me.

Comment: No Dave, It is just like using a native View in android. Just try it and then update your xml!

Comment: Done. Thanks. If I'm referencing this in the MainActivity code, e.g.    DrawingPanel dp = (DrawingPanel) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView); How do I change the onDraw(Canvas c), when there is no Canvas to reference?

Comment: @Dave Moore, take a look at this link: http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/android/Android-Drawing-1.pdf and this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLf32M6lUKo